Read SSD hard drive using an adapter
I have an SSD hard drive with Ubuntu 22.04 installed. However, the PC does not start with the hard drive because the update to 24.04 failed. The hard drive is encrypted and the password is known.
How can I read the hard drive or access the data on another Ubuntu PC (also Windows 10 if necessary)?
I know how to purchase and connect such an adapter.

I had a SATA to USB adapter. It worked great for an SSD, but would not work with an older HDD. Make sure you have external power if using HDD as external drive. Often better to use SSD. I converted my smaller M.2 RAM to USB3 adapter to make external SSD. That worked so well I bought another M.2 NVMe drive & NVMe to USB-C adpater that also works with USB3.

Because I don't know how to use the hard drive then. I.B. I don't know how to decrypt the hard drive.

If you installed Ubuntu into an encrypted LVM partition, normally you'd just plug the drive in on a machine running Ubuntu using the adapter and Ubuntu would prompt you for the passphrase. Have you tried just this?

@Hannu you seem to be under the impression that OP downvoted you answer... Nobody can really tell who did that, however your answer has merit besides the fact that it sounds like you're also ranting about encryption itself, which is kinda out of place for an answer... I guess that's why it got downvoted
